# Azure SQL Database Connection Pooling with User Assigned Managed Identity

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-managed-identity

It seems like the EF Core connection pooling is not working correctly with User Assigned Managed identities. My web page makes 3 Ajax calls from my Angular front end to a Web API controller. The controller uses a repository class that contains the `DbContext` that implements `IDisposable`.

We are running .NET Core 3.1 with EF Core using the default dependency container and the default `DbContext` settings, so it's `ServiceLifeTime.Scoped`.

My `DbContext` ctor has code like this for the managed identity.

```
var connection = (Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)Database.GetDbConnection();

var options = new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ManagedIdentityClientId = surveyToolOptions.Value.ManagedIdentityClientId };
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(options);
var token = credential.GetToken(new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://database.windows.net/.default" }));

connection.AccessToken = token.Token;
```

When I look a the session count, it goes up by the 3 connections every time I hit the page. It's never reusing the connections. They also don't go away for about 4-5 minutes.

```
SELECT host_name, Program_name, COUNT(*) 
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions  s
JOIN sys.databases AS d ON s.database_id = d.database_id
GROUP BY host_name, Program_name
```

This is a problem since the Azure SQL database is very limited on the number of sessions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/resource-limits-dtu-single-databases#standard-service-tier

When I switch it over to Standard SQL Server authentication with a User Id and password, it's working as expected.

Do I need to turn connection pooling off when using Managed Identities? That does seem to work, but I'm sure it's taking longer to establish a connection with pooling off.

-Randy

Comment: Each different security context is a separate connect pool. You'll get better scalability if you authenticate to the database using a service account rather than than the end client identity.

Comment: @DanGuzman,   i thought a User Assigned Managed identity is a service account,  or are you saying i should use a System Assigned Managed identity?    It shouldn't be using anything to do with the end user in either case,  at least that's what i thought.

Comment: I misunderstood the credential you were using. I thing @mpeterson's answer should address the issue with pooling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating a new `DBContext` on every request, and it calls `credential.GetToken(...)` in the constructor, you are likely ending up with a different token every time, so the connection cannot be pooled.

Retrieving and storing the token outside of the constructor should fix this.

Comment: Thanks mpeterson!   That was essentially the key.  I had to use a singleton service that gets the token and is injected into the dbContext ctor.